# Why is the UIKEYBOARD height 1024

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uikeyboard

I am trying to get the UIkeyboard height with the following :

```
float keyboardHeight;
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[aNotification userInfo]
                              objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]
                             CGRectValue];
keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.size.height;
```

but the size it returns is 1024.00 . I wanted to know if this is normal.

Comment: on iPhone the height of the keyboard is 216 pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What device are you testing on? On the iPad 3, in landscape, the keyboard's height is 1024 pixels.

Comment: Ah okay am on the ipad 3. Thanks for confirming this. I thought it should be smaller.

Comment: Oh I wanted to ask you if you knew how to prevent the UIKEYBOARD from pushing the UIWEBVIEW up when it shows up.

Comment: @user880562, `UIWebView` has `scrollView` property (may support from >= iOS 5.0) when you getting focts to your `UITextField` you can set contentOffSet for `UIWebView` where you need to change `y` position according to your need!